# "actionview requires activesupport (= 4.2.4)" error - Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I'm a newbie, thanks for your patience. Trying to install Ruby on Mac 10.10.5 Yosemite. Following steps in https://gorails.com/setup/osx/10.10-yosemite to install Rails. reached point where I need to run "gem install rails -v 4.2.4" in Terminal and get error message "Successfully installed activesupport-4.2.5
ERROR:  Error installing rails:
    actionview requires activesupport (= 4.2.4)"

Googled it, found nothing. What am I supposed to do to fix it? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

gem install activesupport -v 4.2.4